# Python single line while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I am trying to make a variable increment in value while it is less than another number. I know that it is possible to do a `for` loop in the form `(print(x) for x in range(1, 5))`. My question is, is there a similar way to do a `while` loop in this form, such as `x += 1 while x < y`?

Comment: what you are describing is a generator expression, which works with for only

Comment: Ok. That's good to know.

Comment: As indicated by @njzk2 generator expressions work only with for but must be enclosed with ( ).  A bare call to `print(x) for x in range(1,5)` is a syntax error.

Comment: *Why is a single line important?* this is rhetorical, the only correct answer is *it's not*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 0
y = 10
while x < y:
    x +=1

>>> x
10
```

Well you can do it in a single line because Python allows that:

```
x = 0
while x < y: x +=1
```

It is not as readable, and it doesn't conform to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but it is doable.

Comment: This works, but I wanted to do it in one line. If it's not possible, however, i'll accept this one.

Comment: Oh yeah, I never thought of that... well, I have to wait ten minutes to accept. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can separate each statement with a semi-colon like so...

`x = 0; y = 5
while(x < y): print(x); x=x+1`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
n = 0 
while n < 1000: rn += n if not (n % 3 and n % 5) else 0
```

What you are seeing is a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) but it comes at the price of some reduced readability